# Grails query from multiples domains

Tags: sql, hibernate, grails, hql, grails-orm

I have issues. Please help me if you can.

I have 3 domains called:

```
  class DomainA {
    long id
    String propA1
    String propA2
    static hasMany = [domaniBs:DomainB]
  }

  class DomainB {
    long id
    String propB1
    String propB2
    static belongsTo = [forgeinKeyToDomainA:DomainA] 
    static hasMany = [domaniCs:DomainC]
  }

  class DomainC {
    long id
    String  propC1
    String propC2
    static belongsTo = [forgeinKeyToDomainB:DomainB]
  }
```

Want to get all record from DomainC that propA1="value1"

**Imaging SQL code:**

```
Select DomainC.* 
from DomainA,DomainB,DomainC
where DomainA.id=DomainB.forgeinKeyToDomainA
and DomainB.id=DomainC.forgeinKeyToDomainB
and DomainA.propA1="value1"
```

Can execute the SQL code in grails, but want to use Hibernate query.

Comment: What do you mean by "can execute in grails and want to use Hibernate"? Want it in HQL? Or is it something else?

Comment: I installed hibernate plugin inside grails, and I want Hibernate methods to do those.

def instantAlerts = Alert.where {frequently==(Frequently.findByID("instant"))}.list()
instantAlerts.each{instantAlert->
   def resultsInstantAlerts = KetQuaThongBaoEmail.where {sendStatus==0}.list()
   resultsInstantAlerts.each{result->
    emailService.sendInstantNotification(result.alert.user.email,result.food)
 result.sendStatus=1 // Update is sent
 result.save(flush:true)
 }
}

Comment: I finished my task, but I searching others way(searching better way)

Comment: Add that to your answer. It will be better to see and understand (and help you).

Comment: Add??? What do you want? I don't undertand.

Comment: Ops, I meant, to your question. Add the thing you just said to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this.

HQL:

```
DomainC.executeQuery("""
Select c
from DomainA a join a.domainB b join b.domainC c
where a.propA1 = "value1"
""")
```

Dynamic finders

```
DomainC.findAllByDomainBInList(DomainB.findAllByDomainAInList(DomainA.findAllByPropA1("value1"))
```

Comment: Nguyen Le. I would say you must add sample input and output as well to your question so that we know what data you wanted. For your question above query from @James makes sense. Also, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6707438/the-use-of-join-in-grails-gorm-queries